# I need to identify not used parameter in ADF pipeline, any suggestion how I can do this. later after identification I need to remove them as well

Tags: parameters, oracle-adf

I need to identify not used parameter in ADF pipeline, any suggestion how I can do this. later after identification I need to remove them as well.

I checked Pipeline parameter and activity parameter as well but there is nothing available (as per my knowledge) from where I can identify if any parameter getting used or not

Comment: ADF pipelines are defined as JSON. Just do a text search on the JSON for your parameter. If you only find it once (in the parameter definition) then it's not used anywhere else

Comment: As per my knowledge Json is just script view of ADF pipeline. so , you will get all parameter mentioned in .json whatever created on Pipeline or Pipeline's activity but from that it will not be clear that if this parameter is getting used while running whole pipeline . for example if any pipeline has 5 paramter a,b,c,d,e then you will find these paramter in .json but actually only 3 paramater a,b and c is getting used when pipeline will actually run. so from .json I think it will not be clear if parameter is getting actually used in pipeline or not

Comment: If the parameter is _not_ being used you will only find it _once_ in the JSON. If a parameter _is_ being used you'll find it more than once in the JSON. You could also just remove the parmeter in the UI and see if the pipeline saves without error.